# uWSGI "buffer-size" equivalent in Hypercorn / Quart

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, quart, hypercorn

Good night, i'm new in Hypercorn / uvloop / Quart and would  i have to know which configuration in Hypercorn  is equivalent the "buffer-size" from uWSGI?
One detail, my application will not use websockets. In some cases will be sent some big requests with big body and big header. I solve this problem in uWSGI with "buffer-size" and would i like know a equivalent configuration in Hypercorn / uvloop?

Answer (score 0):

`buffer-size` in uWSGI is the maximum size of a request excluding the body. In Hypercorn for HTTP/1 there is the `h11_max_incomplete_size` and for HTTP/2 the `h2_max_header_list_size` and `h2_max_inbound_frame_size`. These have sensible defaults, but you may need to increase them.

In terms of the request body, Quart sets the [`MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH`](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/discussion/dos_mitigations.html#large-request-body) which you can increase as well.